# Runas command fails to work when run in a Standard User?

Tags: windows-11, administrator, runas, command-line-tool

I'm having an issue with the command line command; runas. As per [this](https://superuser.com/q/661979/531729) question, regardless of what switches I use with this command as the linked question I continuously get prompted for the Administration password that works successfully when not used in conjunction with the `runas` command. Otherwise when using the `runas` command and prompted for an Administration password, it doesn't work.

This is not a matter that I'm using the command or it's associated switches incorrectly, rather why I could enter in the administrator password a dozen times, not that entering a dozen times changes anything but that it will not execute the desired program as an administrator when run within a standard user account. As I simple example;

```
runas /user:Christoher-PC/Christopher_Admin cmd.exe
```

The first Christoher-PC is the name of the computer, the second is the name of the Administrator account. In other words, if I right click on the command prompt window, I will be asked for the administrator password, I enter in that password and command prompt is run as an elevated mode, that mode being an administrator.

Although running `runas` for a program short-cut in the Target field of the short cuts properties the administrator password does not work ?

Comment: The syntax uses an anti-slash : `runas /user:Christoher-PC\Christopher_Admin cmd`.

Comment: Thanks, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax to use is with an anti-slash :

```
runas /user:Christoher-PC\Christopher_Admin cmd
```